# Estimate distance between one reference column and several columns in r using a for loop?

Tags: r, geosphere

I have a data frame (df) with the following structure:

```
ID   Long_Ref   Lat_Ref    Long_1   Lat_1    Long_2   Lat_2
A    -71.69     -33.39    -70.29   -33.39   -71.69   -34.19
B    -72.39     -34.34    -74.29   -31.19   -70.54   -33.38
C    -70.14     -32.38    -70.62   -32.37   -69.76   -32.22
D    -70.39     -33.54    -70.42   -34.99   -68.69   -32.33
```

I am trying to append new columns into my existing data frame with the distance between Ref and 1, Ref and 2, etc using distHaversine.

This is the code the i have worked through so far:

```
for (i in 1:2){
for (j in 1:nrow(df)){
df[,paste("Dist_Mts_",i,sep="")][j]<-distHaversine(matrix(c(df$Long_Ref,df$Lat_Ref),ncol=2),
                      matrix(c(as.matrix(df[,paste("Long_",i,sep="")]),
                               as.matrix(df[,paste("Lat_",i,sep="")])),ncol=2))
 }
}
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in .pointsToMatrix(p2) * toRad : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In .pointsToMatrix(p2) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a number of points which might be greater than 2 which you'd like to calculate the distances to, you could do something like this (without using a `for` loop):

```
point.no <- 1:2 # depending on how many points you have

library(tidyverse)
point.no %>% 
  map(~ paste0(c('Long_', 'Lat_'), .x)) %>% 
  setNames(paste0('Dist_Mts_', point.no)) %>% 
  map_df(~ distHaversine(df[c('Long_Ref', 'Lat_Ref')], df[.x]))
```

If you only need to compute the distances to those two points then you could just write this:

```
list(Dist_Mts_1=c('Long_1', 'Lat_1'), Dist_Mts_2=c('Long_2', 'Lat_2')) %>% 
  map_df(~ distHaversine(df[c('Long_Ref', 'Lat_Ref')], df[.x]))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Dist_Mts_1 Dist_Mts_2
       <dbl>      <dbl>
1     130123      89056
2     393159     201653
3      45141      39946
4     161437     208248
```

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)